# how to restore instance once the session is terminated in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm using google colab for a tensorflow project. but whenever I terminate the session all the files and work I've done gets wiped out all there is the ipynb file which I was using. then I have to redo everything from the beginning. these are the file[image]

I loose all these files which I'm using then reupload them when I open my ipynb file the next time. how can solve this problem. should I push this entire file structure to git repo and clone it next time I'm using it? or is their another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

amanpreet!. Yes , you can put all your files in Github ,you can also put all the files in your google drive and access it by mounting drive in Colab . attaching an article for your reference.

https://buomsoo-kim.github.io/colab/2020/05/09/Colab-mounting-google-drive.md/